# what is the proper way to handle this git merge notification scenario?

Tags: bash, git

I just did a git push and I got the following git notification:

```
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:xxxxxxxx
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
# 
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

The git bash console got into a weird state where it asks me to enter a commit message.  So I just typed "git told me to" and hit enter but the git bash console appears to still be in a weird state.

I think I've encountered this scenario in the past and I simply closed the git bash window, then repoened it and went along with my business.  My question is, is that the standard way to handle this scenario?  Or is there a more appropriate and proper/structured way to handle this scenario?

Comment: can you please give us the output of the command `git status`

Comment: yeah I just closed that window and opened a new git bash window and went about my normal routine.  I guess I'll just accept that weird merge console state as a quirk of working git, and not worry about it

Comment: I think even if you will do the same command you will end up with the same result because you haven't properly finished your git command by closing your terminal. so a `git status` can help right now :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your state can be handled. However, your description is unclear to me. Git shouldn't do a `merge` operation if you do a push. Did it suggest that you `pull` first, which then turns into a `fetch` and a `merge` operation? In that case, just one note: It's a suggestion. You can `reset` to the origin, `merge` with the origin or `rebase` on the origin. You can also tell git to `push` to the origin, overwriting what is there. It depends which one is the right tool for your case.

Comment: Did you push or pull? This is usually seen on pull (as in https://github.com/jteresco/GitFixes#merging-with-git-pull), not push

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like "this" in a title that require someone to click through and read the question to know what it's actually about.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Git will prompt you for a commit message when merging a branch, so you can explain why your merge is necessary (as the description says).  It populates a default message, and if you're happy with that message and don't want to provide a further message, you can just save and quit your editor, and the default message will be used.

If you don't want to edit the commit message when performing a merge, you can set the environment variable `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` to `no` and it won't prompt.  You can set this set in your shell configuration, and if you then *do* want to edit it in a particular case, you can pass the `--edit` option.

Note that the message you're seeing isn't a notification, but an editor window, which is why the terminal may appear to be in a weird state.  If your default editor happens to be Vim, you'll probably want to save and quit by typing Escape and then `:wq` and Enter.  You can set a different editor by default by changing the `core.editor` option.